# calculated integral bounded by Y axis

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

suppose we want to  find Find the area bounded by the curve
$y=\sqrt{2*x-1}$

$Y$ axis   and lines $y=1$ and $y=2$

as i remember ,i should express $x$ as a function of $y$ and calculate

$\int(f(y)dy$

so in this case,we have   $y^2=2*x-1$  or

$x=(y^2+1)/2=y^2/2+1/2$

so integral from $y=1$ to  $y=2$ is $10/6$,because  anti derivative  of $y^2/2+1/2$ is $y^3/6+y/2$ and put values,is this correct?thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: thanks in advance,you can post general solution and i will accept it

Comment: It's your solution, so fairer that you post it and I'll vote up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the are and the shape it has, you may find that area as follows easier.  An square with area of $1\times 1$ and the rest as $$\int_1^{5/2} (2-y)dx$$

[image]

Comment: +1 even though I *hate* pink! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: You do? Isn't it because of the nickname of that singer, Pink?

Comment: Nice illustration +1